# Rails 4.2 : How disable encryption for cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-4-upgrade

I recently upgraded my rails 3.2 app to rails 4.2. I face the issue of cookies set by new rails 4.2 is signed and  encrypted which I don't won't because my application interacts with other rails 3 apps. 
I want to reintroduce old way to created cookies in 4.2.

Comment: Does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134675/4950680) answers your question? If so please mark it as complete

Answer (score 1):

Thats true that Rails 4 [CookieStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html) encrypt cookies by default:

> If you have secret_key_base set, your cookies will be encrypted. This
>   goes a step further than signed cookies in that encrypted cookies
>   cannot be altered or read by users. This is the default starting in
>   Rails 4.

It seems like there is no way to turn this off through config options so one way is to dont set `secret_key_base`.

Another is to define your custom session store with redefined [CookieStore#cookie_jar](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb#L112) method:

```
class ActionDispatch::Session::MyCustomStore < ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
  private

  def cookie_jar(request)
    request.cookie_jar.signed
  end
end
```

And in `config.rb`:

```
config.session_store :my_custom_store
```

This way your cookies will be held in [signed](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies/ChainedCookieJars.html#method-i-signed) jar like in Rails 3.